# The difference between the machine type in Vertex ai workbench instance and aiplatform SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline

What is the difference between the machine type which we set in Vertex ai workbench for Notebook and the machine type in python SDK of [aiplatform.CustomTrainingJob](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/index.html?highlight=customtraining#google.cloud.aiplatform.CustomTrainingJob.run) run method? The machine type is already provisioned for notebook, so why we are specifying it again inside the script of the notebook?!